# Pagination Codeigniter using twig

Tags: php, codeigniter, twig

Anybody know how configure `base_url` in pagination CodeIgniter using twig?

**Case is:** I can create pagination using CI Pagination Library and it success.

I use config pagination below:

```
$config['base_url'] = "product/page";
```

and in view for the firs page it's success, when I click next pagination URL right too but CSS link change to `localhost/myweb/product/page/assets/css/style.css`.
so i can load that CSS coz css i put in `localhost/myweb/assets/css/style.css`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check config base_url in codeigniter config,
base_url must be like this : 
if you using local server as XAMPP :
$config['base_url'] = `http://localhost/{yoursite}`;

don't missed type "http://" => it's important!

Comment: Gotcha.... Thank hary, im setting base url completely and register function in global funcion twig, so i'v change setting all asset using {{ base_url() }}. its done !! :)

Answer (score 1):

About pagination, you can just use:

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url("/product/page");
```

No Twig matter here.

About `base_url()` available in Twig, you should add helpers to your Twig library (eg. the implementation of Twig inside `application/libraries` of your CI project) as Twig extensions. If your `application/libraries/Twig.php` class contains the twig environment as `_twig_env` attribute, you can use something like:

```
public function __construct()
{
   // ...

   $this->ci_function_init();
} 

public function ci_function_init_one($twig_name, $callable)
{
   $this->_twig_env->addFunction(
     new Twig_SimpleFunction($twig_name, $callable, array('is_safe' => array('html')))
   );
}

public function ci_function_init()
{
  // url
  $this->ci_function_init_one('base_url', 'base_url');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('site_url', 'site_url');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('current_url', 'current_url');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('current_path', 'current_path');

  // form functions
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_open', 'form_open');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_hidden', 'form_hidden');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_input', 'form_input');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_password', 'form_password');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_upload', 'form_upload');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_textarea', 'form_textarea');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_dropdown', 'form_dropdown');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_multiselect', 'form_multiselect');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_fieldset', 'form_fieldset');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_fieldset_close', 'form_fieldset_close');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_checkbox', 'form_checkbox');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_radio', 'form_radio');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_submit', 'form_submit');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_label', 'form_label');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_reset', 'form_reset');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_button', 'form_button');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_close', 'form_close');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_prep', 'form_prep');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('set_value', 'set_value');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('set_select', 'set_select');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('set_checkbox', 'set_checkbox');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('set_radio', 'set_radio');
  $this->ci_function_init_one('form_open_multipart', 'form_open_multipart');
}
```

You're now able to use `{{ base_url() }}` in your twig templates.

Comment: Thanks Alain, you're right it's no matter with twig, solution is i have to set global variable "base url"  and register it to twig function then i can call it with {{ base_url }} in view template. Thank for your answer Alain.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `base_url()` or `site_url()` function on css/js files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo site_url('assets/css/style.css'); ?>">
```

or using `base href` magic tag that always show base url:

```
<base href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>">
```